# Warning : previous definition of Variable was here - Ruby

Tags: ruby

Every single time I load my program, even for the fist time, it says

```
file.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant W_mum
file.rb:6: warning: previous definition of W_mum was here.
```

a little help here?

```
W_mum = gets.to_i

elsif (W_mum = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby uses two different "storage bins" for data: variables and constants. In your source code, you can identify them y their first letter: constants always have a capital letter at the start of their name, variables a lower-case letter.

In your case, you thus have a constant named `W_mum`. Now, when you first set a value to a constant and then later set a different value to it, Ruby will show a  warning (as such: you *can* set new values to constants, but you should not).

Now, as for why Ruby warns here: in your `elsif`, you are actually assigning the constant the value `1`. This might be a bug though. Instead of an assignment with `=`, you likely intended to use a comparison here, using the `==` operator.

Comment: Thanks! This Helped a lot! _now how do i close this question?_

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful. You can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217589) and upvote if you like, exactly as you did here.

Comment: Please see "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773)"
and "[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994)"